# How to catch a event of AutoSuggestBox in Pivot_SelectionChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

```
private void SuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
        {

            if(args.QueryText!=null)
            {
                ...

            }

        }
Pivot_SelectionChanged
private void privotContent_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            SuggestBox.QuerySubmitted += SuggestBox_QuerySubmitted;
        }
```

don't call SuggestBox.QuerySumitted in privotContent. But I want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to fire the `QuerySubmitted` event of a `AutoSuggestBox` inside of the `SelectionChanged` event of a `Pivot` control. You can for example code like this:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ee = new AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs();
    AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(autoSuggestBox, ee);
}

private void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.QueryText != null)
    {
    }
}
```

the `autoSuggestBox` in this code is the `Name` of the `AutoSuggestBox` control.